# RHEL 6, Mounting Network Storage at Boot

Tags: network-share, mount, rhel6

I have multiple network folders that need to be accessed by RHEL machine for a server program.  The issue is everytime the server gets rebooted all the mounts get erased.

How can I make it so the mounts are permanent? Is there a way to do it without storing user credentials in plain text?

Comment: What file sharing protocol?

Comment: The machines I am mounting to are windows 2008 R2 servers

Comment: Mounting to?  But you said in the question that you're mounting them to an RHEL machine.  Do you mean they're mounted **from** a W2k8R2 box?  And in any case, that still doesn't tell us the protocol (it suggests SMB, but it could also be NFS, for a start).

Answer (score 2):

Enable the `netfs` service.

```
service netfs start
```

Just make sure that the netfs service is set to start upon boot. This can be done in the `ntsysv` menu or by a simple `chkconfig netfs on`. Reboot and the NFS and SMB/CIFS mounts defined in /etc/fstab will mount as requested.

Answer (score 2):

add the mounts in /etc/fstab with the "`credentials=filename`" option where you specify a file that contains the username and password, of the form

```
username=value
password=value
domain=value
```

See the man page for details: `man mount.cifs`

Comment: That's my issue, the username and password are stored in plain text.  I need a solution where the passwords are not stored in the plain text.

Comment: I don't know of any way to do this.